# Translation of John Doe

Tags: single-word-request, english-to-german

(At least) in America, not yet identified dead persons are named *"John (or Jane) Doe"*. If you read of a *John/Jane Doe*, then you know that this is a still unknown dead man/woman.

Does any similar term exist in the german language?

[dict.leo.org](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=John%20Doe) suggests "Otto Normalverbraucher", but I don't think that this matches.

Comment: Indeed, "Otto Normalverbraucher" doesn't match at all. That's used in a completely different context.

Comment: It's not only for dead people. Unidentified people that are the target of litigation are also called Does. For that I don't think there is an equivalent.

Comment: We also have "N.N.", "Lieschen Müller", "Erika Mustermann" and "Max Mustermann", but they aren't quite the same either. http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Doe#Bedeutung

Answer (score 42, accepted):

John Doe can mean different things:

- As you say, an unidentified corpse. In German you'd go the long way and say something like "eine (noch) nicht identifizierte Leiche" ("a (yet) unidentified corpse"). The [Wikipedia article](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Doe) also mentions "N.N." for "Nomen nominandum" which curiously redirects to "Nomen nescio" in the English WP. But I don't know Latin...
- A fictional person that represents the general public (Joe Sixpack is also common, I like that one). Here you'd use *Otto Normalverbraucher*.
- A placeholder name for sample documents. Here *Max Mustermann* (or *Erika Mustermann*) is almost exclusively used.
- An unknown target in a litigation (e.g. you only have an IP address without a name). In criminal law this is known as "Anzeige gegen unbekannt" ("charges against person or persons unknown").

Comment: +1 for the *Mustermann* family.

Comment: For ligitations it's usually "Anzeige gegen Unbekannt" (= "charges against unknown persons" or "charges against an unknown person")

Comment: @Joachim: How could I miss that...

Comment: By the way, in German you'd rather say "eine *nicht* identifizierte Leiche", rather than *unidentifiziert*, especially in official contexts. *Unidentifiziert* is not wrong though, just much less common. Great answer anyway.

Comment: "Nomen nominandum" which curiously redirects to "Nomen nescio"
"Nomen nominandum" heißt: Der Name muss (erst noch) genannt werden. "Nomen nescio" heißt: Ich kenne den Namen nicht. Die erste Übersetzung passt also besser in Fällen, wo der Name absichtlich geheimgehalten wird.

Comment: It's also "Monika Mustermann" instead of Erika. ;)

Comment: @ladybug: The corresponding article in the Wikipedia says *Erika*. In fact a search for *Max Mustermann* redirects to *Erika Mustermann*. There are many names though: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Mustermann#Andere_Mitglieder_der_Familie_Mustermann. My favorite quote is "Die deutschen EU-Führerschein-Muster sind auf die Zwillingsschwestern Desiré Jeanette und Anne Mustermann [...] ausgestellt."

Comment: ...erm, sorry, my English sentence was plain wrong. ^^ What I actually wanted to express was: "Instead of Erika, there are also other names used, e.g. Monika Mustermann". :)

Comment: @Joachim: So in germany, we also have female criminals. :)

Comment: Well, the most hardened female criminal we had was the phantom of Heilbronn: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantom_of_Heilbronn

Comment: By the way, Otto Normalverbraucher translates to Otto Average-Consumer, or less literally to "John Q. Public"

Answer (score 13):

Whenever an unknown person needs a name for administrative purposes the gender and estimated age is used in a hospital emergency room setting:

> weiblich, [unbekannt], 30 Jahre
>
> männlich, [unbekannt], 70 Jahre

where [unbekannt] may be omitted.

Another term would be:

> Unbekannte [männl./weibl.] Person, ca. 40 Jahre

where *männlich* or *weiblich* is abbreviated in most cases.

Answer (score 3):

On credit cards, forms etc. (that feature a "sample name") *Hans Mustermann* is often used in CH.

Comment: Yes, but that's because it's a _sample_, not because it's _unknown_.

Comment: I consider this a legitimate example of a "random" name.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there actually is an equivalent. I've never heard such a name in German news. If there is an unidentified person found dead the usual way to reference him/her would be "that unidentified man/woman we found the other day".

Answer (score 0):

rarely used, for a person, where the name doesn't matter:

> Meier, Müller, Schulz

3 very common surnames.

> "Das erledigt dann Meier, Müller, Schulz."